# Помогите понять логику стандартного конструктора класса-наследника

Tags: php

```
<?php

abstract class AParent
{
    protected function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
        echo $param1, ' ', $param2; // Выведет 1122 3344
    }

    public static function create($param1, $param2)
    {
        return new static($param1, $param2);
    }
}

final class Child extends AParent
{
    /*
    protected function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
        parent::__construct($param1, $param2);
    }
    */
}

$obj = Child::create(1122, 3344); // Выведет 1122 3344
```

Пожалуйста, помогите понять. Откуда стандартный конструктор класса Child знает, что параметры, переданные ему, нужно передать конструктору родительского класса?

Comment: а вы как себе механизм наследования вообще представляете?

Comment: Вызывается последний переопределенный конструктор

Comment: @teran, да я раздолбай, с ооп только недавно начал знакомство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберем, что происходит поэтапно.

Вызываем статичный метод `create` класса `Child`

```
$obj = Child::create(1122, 3344);
```

Так как класс не имеет метода create, то он использует метод класса родителя `AParent`

```
public static function create($param1, $param2)
{
    return new static($param1, $param2);
}
```

Данный метод создает объект класса, в котором мы вызываем метод, тоесть сработает его конструктор, а так как у `Child` нет конструктора, то вызывается конструктор родителя `AParent`.

```
protected function __construct($param1, $param2)
{
    echo $param1, ' ', $param2; // Выведет 1122 3344
}
```

**Fun fact**

`new static` создает объект класса, откуда был вызов. Тоесть в вашем случае ваш объект имеет класс `Child`. В случае если нужно создать объект класса родителя, не зависимо от того, что метод идет от наследника, нужно использовать `new self`

Comment: вы сведения из документации снабжаете заголовком `fun fact`?

Comment: При отсутствии метода конструктора у наследника, с переданными параметрами вызывается конструктор предка, верно?

<?php

abstract class Grandfather
{
    protected function __construct($param)
    {
        echo "$param\n";
        echo get_class();
    }

}

abstract class Father extends Grandfather
{

}

final class Child extends Father
{
    public static function create($param1)
    {
        return new static($param1);
    }
}

$obj = Child::create(100500); // Будет вызван конструктор класса Grandfather

Comment: За Fun fact спасибо, об этом я, слава Богу, знаю :)

Comment: да, верно. Конструктор это тот же метод, полиморфизм его стороной не обходит.

Comment: @Jurij Jazdanov, спасибо вам!